# git is not running after update on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: macos

After updating to MacOS Big Sur (Version 11.0.1) I started my projects as usual trying to do some git commands.

I always receive:

```
git status               
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

I might oversee some threads, you can link them here as well when there are already ones.

Thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: Reinstalling the xcode command line tools is a good place to start.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue after I updated Mac OS to Big Sur (version 11.2). Running `sudo xcode-select --install` in terminal solved it.